# In db2 how the sum function works

Tags: sql, db2

```
select 
 sum(TOTALPRODUCT+TOTALADJUSTMENT),
 orders_id
from orders
where orders_id=7023771
```

can some one please suggest why this query is giving error.

Please suggest the reason behind it.

Comment: Why do you think it should produce an error? And what error?

Comment: Are TOTALPRODUCT and TOTALADJUSTMENT both columns in the "orders" table? If so, just 'SELECT TOTALPRODUCT + TOTALADJUSTMENT, orders_id... If no, how are these calculated?

Comment: @mustaccio: of course this will generate an error because it's missing a `group by orders_id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -- of course it does, but the original question was why the query would **not** produce an error, so I was curious about what was on the OP's mind. (I hate it when someone posts a bizarre statement then edits it away, leaving me looking like a fool with my comments :)